# How to set a custom header using phpmailer

Tags: email, header, phpmailer, return-path

I am using phpmailer for sending emails, but I want to make a custom header for my company, by adding a textarea field that contain any custom header for example using a header like this one:

[exemple of header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4afxd.jpg)
or any other header types..
How can I do this , thanks in advance.

Comment: It's up to you to write a parser for fields like that, but once you've done that, PHPMailer will be happy to add them as real custom headers using the `addCustomHeader() `function. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i need more explanation please , pratical exemple if you can :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You will need to do some discovery and modification of the default headers set by PHPmailer for this to be achieved.

You will need to use different functions to set/edit headers depending on the type of header you want to set/edit. Here are a few examples:

From:

```
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
```

Subject:

```
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
```

Custom:

```
$mail->addCustomHeader('X-custom-header', 'custom-value');
```

In short, It is quite an effort to do this when the headers are free-typed in a text box. It is however doable with detection and validation on your side.

Comment: thank you for you quick response , but if you can give me a pratical exemple for this picture http://i.stack.imgur.com/4afxd.jpg

Comment: You're offering security training and you don't know what parsing means? Sounds a bit spammy to me.

Comment: i know what parsing means  , but it a bit difficult in this case

Comment: If you think this is difficult, you *really* don't know what parsing means.

Comment: If you want to do even less parsing, you can send the name and value together, like `$mail->addCustomHeader('X-custom-header: custom-value');` https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php