# How to modify the default header using phpmailer

Tags: email, parsing, header, phpmailer

I am using phpmailer for sending emails, but I want to make a custom header for my company, by adding a textarea field that contain any custom header for example using a header like this one:

```
Subject: __Subject
From: __From
Reply-to: <__Reply-To> 
To: __To
Date: __smtpDate
```

or any other header types.. How can I do this in details please, thanks in advance.

Comment: post your code it will be easy to recognize your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a custom header using phpmailer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36927416/how-to-set-a-custom-header-using-phpmailer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To parse the fields into an array (assuming your textarea is called `mytextarea`):

```
$headers = [];
foreach (preg_split('/[\r\n]+/', $_POST['mytextarea']) as $line) {
    list($name, $value) = explode(': ', $line, 2);
    $headers[$name] = $value;
}

var_dump($headers);
```

Then you can iterate over that array and process each header. Most of the headers you have listed require special handling, for example `Subject` should be put into `$mail->Subject`, not used with `addCustomHeader`. All that is covered in the PHPMailer docs and examples, so there is no point in expanding that here.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `addCustomHeader()` method

> Provides ability for user to create own custom headers (like
>   X-Priority, for example).

Example use:

```
$mail->addCustomHeader("X-Priority: 3");
```

---

SRC: http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#method_addCustomHeader

Comment: please give me an exemple for this header : Subject: __Subject
From: __From
Reply-to: <__Reply-To>
To: __To
Date: __smtpDate

Comment: Why are you pointing links back to obsolete resources after I've corrected them? As the package maintainer I have to fight against this tide of crap every day.